# Want to make http get request only if text is typed in input field ANGULARJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, http-get, angular-promise

The data is coming from a local json file, but I want it to make an http.get request only when `searchText` (on a keypress)  is typed in input field

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchText">
```

I will show the results in the following table:

```
<table ng-if="searchText" class="searchResults table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive"> 
  <tr>
    <th>DLL ID</th>
    <th>KVK Nummer</th>
    <th>Company Name</th>
  </tr>

  <tr ng-repeat="data in getData | filter: customFilter">
   <td>{{data.Id}}</td>
   <td>{{data.stTax_ID_VAT_Number}}</td>
   <td>{{data.AccountName}}</td>
</table>
```

In the controller I have so far following:

```
    $scope.searchText = undefined;

    if($scope.searchText){
    $http.get('data/json_sample/DV_IC_01.json')
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.allData = data;
                $scope.getData = $scope.allData.d.results;
            });
}
    $scope.customFilter = function(row){
        if (!$scope.searchText){
                return true;
            }

        return (row.stTax_ID_VAT_Number.indexOf($scope.searchText) !== -1) || (row.AccountName.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchText.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
    }
```

Comment: send $http on ng-keypress and also check value of seachText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the directive `ng-change`.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchText" ng-change="getData()">
```

Inside your controller:

```
$scope.getData = function(){
  //implement your $http logic.
}
```

Comment: I do not see that option, should I add text to heading?

Comment: Under the upvote/downvote score to the top left of my answer, there should be a check-mark. Just click it to mark the question as resolved.